# Jquery Custom Rules Validation with Depends and Param Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

So i have a html drop down box with 4 values A,B,C and D. And 4 pre filled text-boxes(P1,P2,P3,P4) with some texts in them, and 4 blank text boxes(B1,B2,B3 and B4).

I want validations to be applied on the basis of what value is selected in dropdownbox.

if drop-down value is A, i want to only check that value in the Blank Textbox B1 is not equal to value in pre populated text box P1 and B1 can't be left as blank as well.

Same for Dropdown box value with B - > P2.val != B2.val, and B2 shouldn't be blank. and same applies for other.

And i came up with this method for One textbox, but its not working somehow, not sure what is wrong. Would appreciate a solution to my problem.

And the intended result for the below code piece is, when dropdownbox has value A in it, it should only then, proceed to check that the value in two text boxes is same, i.e. in P1 and B1. !!

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <select class="inlineEdit" name="Dropdownbox" id="Dropdownbox">
    <option value="A">
        A
    </option><option value="B">
        B
    </option><option value="C">
        C
    </option><option value="D">
        D
    </option>
</select>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text"  name="P1" value="Old Value" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text"  name="B1" />
    <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("change", function(value, element, param) {
alert(param + " " + value);
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
}, jQuery.format("You must enter {0}"));


$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        B1: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#Dropdownbox").val() == "A";
            },
            change: {
                param: $("#P1").val(),
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $("#Dropdownbox").val() == "A";
                }
            }
        }
    },

    debug: true
});​
```

........

One can try to run the above code here at : http://jsfiddle.net/

**THe Problem is $("#P1").val is sending true, and not the actual value in param, that is why it is not working. If i hard code the values in param, the code works fine. any solutions ???**

Thanks,

Comment: Are you missing a # in front of DropdownA?

Comment: amm no, i am placing #sign in the original code.

Comment: Well it makes it more difficult if you're not posting the original code, but I can also see that you're missing a closing } after the change object (you close out depends, but not change)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, but i believe the problem is semantic not  the syntax. :\ Is the above code semantically correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

It may be that you're missing the # sign in front of P1.  If you're tryign to identify P1 as the name, that requires a `$('[name="P1"]')`.  For catching thigns like this, it would help if you could include the actual code, rather than putting in default strings.  Similarly, it looks like you're identifying B1 by name.  If it is instead the id or class or something, that would be your problem.  For reasons such as this, having a code sample containing the pertinent HTML might also be helpful.

Other than that, what effects *are* you seeing?  When answering questions like this, it is often helpful to have both the intended result and actual result.

Not an answer so much as a suggestion, given that you're having semantic concerns, I tend to prefer keeping all of the logic in the jQuery.Validator.addMethod call, as it helps keep the semantics a bit simpler, and all of it in the same place.  I can't see anything wrong with your semantics myself.

edit: yep.  Like I thought.  You're using `$("#P1")`.  This will give you the node with Id of "P1".  In order to use JQuery to get by name, you need to use `$('[name="P1"]')`.  Alternately, you can set your HTML so that the appropriate tag has an id that matches its name (as you did with Dropdownbox).

Comment: Ben, i updated the code to include # symbols here, i hope it would limit the confusions.  And the intended result for the above piece is, when dropdownbox has value A in it,  it should only then, proceed to check that the value in two text boxes is same, i.e. in P1 and B1. !!

Comment: Could you put this into a jsfiddle? It's just kind of hard to help someone debug something when you're only looking at a part of the problem.

Comment: I Put the above to jsfiddle, it compiled with no errors. but still not working. I doubt on params and depends properties. any clue ?

Comment: Thanks Ben. :) Never thought the problem would be this tiny. Thanks for support 1